# how to make clean code in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, dry

how to make this code clean in rails?

profiles_controller.rb :

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_profile, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
   @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    profile, message = Profile.create_object(params["profile"], current_user)
    flash[:notice] = message
    redirect_to profile_url
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    profile, message = @profile.update_object(params["profile"])
    flash[:notice] = message
    redirect_to profile_url
  end

  private
    def find_profile
      @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params["id"])
    end

end
```

i look flash[:notice] and redirct_to profile_url is duplicate in my code, how to make the code to clean and dry?

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the repetitive code to a separate method and call that method inside the actions.

```
def flash_redirect # you can come up with a better name
   flash[:notice] = message
   redirect_to profile_url
end
```

then in `update` action:

```
def update
   profile, message = @profile.update_object(params["profile"])
   flash_redirect
end
```

do the same thing for `create` action

UPDATE:

in case you are wondering about using`after_action`, you can't use it to redirect as the call-back is appended after the action runs out its course. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802156/update-route-in-rails-doesnt-respond-well-to-after-action)

Comment: how to make method flash_rediret using after_action or after_filter?, so in my code i dont need write flash_redirect in 2 method create and update... i think the code still need clean optimize

Comment: see the link in my updated answer. after_action would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). It's based on the fact that many CRUD controllers in Rails have the exact same general structure. It does most of the work for you and is fully customisable in case things are done a little different in your controllers.

Using this gem, your code would look like this:

```
class ProfilesController < InheritedResources::Base
  def create
    redirect_to_profile(*Profile.create_object(params[:profile], current_user))
  end

  def update
    redirect_to_profile(*@profile.update_object(params[:profile]))
  end

  private
  def redirect_to_profile(profile, message)
    redirect_to(profile_url, notice: message)
  end

  def resource
    @profile ||= Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The create and update methods return multiple values, so I used the [splat operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) to DRY this up.

`create_object` and `update_object` don't follow the Rails default, so we need to implement those actions for Inherited Resources instead. Currently they don't seem to be handling validation errors. If you can, refactor them to use ActiveRecord's `save` and `update`, it would make everything even easier and DRYer.